# How to get two return value from Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle

I know how to get **one return** value from Oracle SP in Oracle as follow

```
MyReturn := MY_ORACLE_SP ();
```

If MY_ORACLE_SP2's return value is **more than one**. How can I do?

Comment: "More than one" _horizontally_ (i.e. multiple fields) or _vertically_ (multiple rows)?

Comment: functions can return only one object. But it can be of complex type (`TABLE OF some_type`). But maybe you would like to use procedures?

Comment: My SP will return two value. That's why I don't know how to get those two return value from my SP.

Comment: Maybe you need an array as a return value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
-- IN arguments : you get them. You can modify them locally but caller won't see it
-- IN OUT arguments: initialized by caller, already have a value, you can modify them and the caller will see it
-- OUT arguments: they're reinitialized by the procedure, the caller will see the final value.
CREATE PROCEDURE f (p IN NUMBER, x IN OUT NUMBER, y OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   x:=x * p;
   y:=4 * p;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare
   foo number := 30;
   bar number := 0;
begin
   f(5,foo,bar);
   dbms_output.put_line(foo || ' ' || bar);
end;
/
```

outputs: 150 20

Answer (score 8):

What you have there is technically not a **procedure**, but a **function** -- the difference being that a procedure does not have a return value and cannot be used as the right-hand-side of an assignment statement.

You basically have two options:

(1) Use OUT parameters.  In this case I would make it a procedure with two OUT parameters.  Generally people don't like functions that also have OUT parameters, as it violates the usual expectations.  @Benoit's answer shows this method.

(2) Define a type that contains multiple values and use this as the return type of the function.  Example:

```
CREATE TYPE two_values AS object (
  A NUMBER,
  b number
  );
  /

CREATE FUNCTION get_two_values RETURN two_values AS
BEGIN
  RETURN two_values(2,4);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTPUT parameters instead of the return value.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below code I just modified the response from user Benoit

```
ab=`sqlplus -s system/password << eof

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
set pagesize 0;
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 5000;
set trimspool on;
declare
   foo number := 30;
   bar number := 0;
begin
   f(5,foo,bar);
   dbms_output.put_line(foo || ' ' || bar);
end;
/

eof`

echo $ab
```