# Is it possible to use "return" in stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Pname(in_Tid IN VARCHAR2,in_IP IN VARCHAR2,outstaticip OUT VARCHAR2,outcount OUT NUMBER)
 AS
 BEGIN
 select STATIC_IP into outstaticip from OP_TTER_MAPPING where TERMINAL_ID = in_Tid;
 if in_IP = outstaticip then
 return 1;
 else
 select COUNT(*) into outcount from OP_TTER_MAPPING where DYNAMIC_IP_LOW <= in_IP AND   DYNAMIC_IP_HIGH >= in_IP AND TERMINAL_ID = in_Tid;
 if outcount = 1 then
 return 1;
 else
 return 0;
  end if;
 end if;
 END;
```

1. Is it possible to use return in stored procedure like above?
2. If we can use return, how can i get that return value in `Executesql("begin Pname(----)END")` method

**EDIT**

Now I edited my return value in stored procedure like this, am I doing it right ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_ValidateTIDIP(in_Tid IN VARCHAR2,in_IP IN VARCHAR2,outstaticip OUT VARCHAR2,outcount OUT NUMBER,outretvalue OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
select STATIC_IP into outstaticip from OP_TTER_MAPPING where TERMINAL_ID = in_Tid;
if in_IP = outstaticip then
    outretvalue:=1;
else 
    select COUNT(*) into outcount from OP_TTER_MAPPING where DYNAMIC_IP_LOW <= in_IP AND DYNAMIC_IP_HIGH >= in_IP AND TERMINAL_ID = in_Tid;
    if outcount = 1 then 
     outretvalue:=1;
    else
     outretvalue:=0;
   end if;
end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Stored procedure, you return the values using `OUT` parameter **ONLY**. As you have defined two variables in your example:

```
   outstaticip OUT VARCHAR2, outcount OUT NUMBER
```

Just assign the return values to the out parameters i.e. `outstaticip` and `outcount` and access them back from calling location.  What I mean here is: when you call the stored procedure, **you will be passing those two variables as well. After the stored procedure call, the variables will be populated with return values.**

If you want to have `RETURN value` as return from the PL/SQL call, then use `FUNCTION`. **Please note that in case, you would be able to return only one variable as return variable.**

Comment: @user1799114: Its not formatted, so hard to undersntand. But looks OK as you seem to assign the values in OUT variables. What is the question  now?

Comment: @user1799114: I am here. what is the question?

Comment: In my question i posted a stored procedure w/o return value, i want to know im going in right way or not.

Comment: @user1799114: You have defined the out parameters and seems to be in right direction. That is the way you work with procedures and better part of using procedure over function is: you may have more than one outputs. Only demerit is that you may not use procedure as inline function in some query.

Comment: @user1799114: I do see one issue. If `in_IP = outstaticip` is `true` then your `outcount` variable is not assigned with any value.

Comment: Thank you yogendra and " I do see one issue. If in_IP = outstaticip is true then your outcount variable is not assigned with any value" Yes u r right how can i overcome that problem?

Comment: @user1799114: The same way, you are dealing with `outretvalue` in `else` section. Assign some default value to `outcount` variable. I am thinking, you don't want to run `select COUNT(*) ...` query to populate `outcount`, when condition is true.

Comment: ok u r saying that i have to assign some default value to 'outcount' if the first 'if' get suceeded.

Comment: @user1799114: That's one way. I am not aware of the functionality of the stored procedure so not able to suggest better. You may decide as per your functional needs.

Answer (score 6):

Use FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

BEGIN
  RETURN 'This is being returned from a function';
END test_function;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
-- IN arguments : you get them. You can modify them locally but caller won't see it
-- IN OUT arguments: initialized by caller, already have a value, you can modify them and the caller will see it
-- OUT arguments: they're reinitialized by the procedure, the caller will see the final value.
CREATE PROCEDURE f (p IN NUMBER, x IN OUT NUMBER, y OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   x:=x * p;
   y:=4 * p;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare
   foo number := 30;
   bar number := 0;
begin
   f(5,foo,bar);
   dbms_output.put_line(foo || ' ' || bar);
end;
/
```

-- Procedure output can be collected from variables x and y (ans1:= x and ans2:=y) will be: 150 and 20 respectively.

-- Answer borrowed from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9484228/1661078

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

When you use Return inside a procedure, the control is transferred to the calling program which calls the procedure. It is like an exit in loops.

It won't return any value.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_emp(dept_id IN NUMBER,vv_ename out varchar2  )
 AS
 v_ename emp%rowtype;
CURSOR c_emp IS
    SELECT ename
    FROM emp where deptno=dept_id;
 BEGIN
     OPEN c;
     loop
        FETCH c_emp INTO v_ename;
        return v_ename; 
        vv_ename := v_ename 
        exit when c_emp%notfound;
     end loop;
     CLOSE c_emp;


 END pr_emp;
```