# PL/SQL return record in procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

I have a procedure which called "gps_coord". It takes two parameter and must return record . But I don't know how I can do it . Thanks in advance ;)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gps_coord(v_x IN FLOAT,
                                      v_y IN FLOAT, v_result out result_type)
IS
TYPE result_type IS RECORD(
     v_km VARCHAR2(50),
     v_objID VARCHAR2(50)
);

v_out result_type;
BEGIN


select P.KM , P.OBJECTID INTO v_out  from SDE.POINTS p where        sde.st_intersects(P.SHAPE,sde.st_buffer(sde.st_transform( sde.st_point(v_y,v_x,4326),32639) ,5000))=1;
 dbms_output.put_line('km: ' || v_out.v_km || 'objid: ' || v_out.v_objID );
END;
```

Comment: The record type must be declared outside the procedure...

Comment: @ammoQ is right, in your case you have an standalone  procedure, to use record type as parameter it must be declared at schema level.

Comment: Please look over [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225532/is-it-possible-to-use-return-in-stored-procedure) question & answer.

Comment: As above...If you place your procedure in a package you can then declare the record type in the package spec.

Comment: Sorry a little mistake, record as I remember can't be schema level, as above declare in package specs or as a schema level object type.

Comment: yeah thank you to all. I declare my type above . And added my procedure  out param with my created type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
    --Object type creation
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE result_type
IS
  OBJECT
  (
    v_km    VARCHAR2(50),
    v_objID VARCHAR2(50) );

--Table type
CREATE OR REPLACE type result_tab
IS
  TABLE OF result_type;

  --Procedure creation and out the collection
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE gps_coord(
    v_x IN FLOAT,
    v_y IN FLOAT,
    v_result OUT result_tab)
AS
  v_out result_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT result_type(P.KM , P.OBJECTID) BULK COLLECT
  INTO v_out
  FROM SDE.POINTS p
  WHERE sde.st_intersects(P.SHAPE,sde.st_buffer(sde.st_transform( sde.st_point(v_y,v_x,4326),32639) ,5000))=1;
  FOR i IN v_out.FIRST..v_out.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_out(i).v_km||' '||v_out(i).v_objID);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @AvrajitRoy  ;) Can I ask question ? I have another problem.When I test my procedure it show me error : "Variant conversion error for value v_x" . Can you help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the input you are passing to the procedure?

Comment: v_x=40.889786  and v_y=45.994247

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE result_type IS OBJECT
(
   v_km NVARCHAR2(50),
   v_objID NVARCHAR2(50)
 )


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gps_coord(v_x IN NVARCHAR2, v_y IN NVARCHAR2,    v_result out result_type)
 IS
  BEGIN
   select P.KM , P.OBJECTID INTO v_result.v_km ,  v_result.v_objID from SDE.POINTS p where sde.st_intersects(P.SHAPE,sde.st_buffer(sde.st_transform( sde.st_point(v_y,v_x,4326),32639) ,5000))=1;
  end;
```