# Only getting string "ReturnValue" back from Oracle and not the actual value

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oledbcommand

I'm inserting into a table that has 2 columns that trigger values upon inserting into the table.

I'm trying to get those 2 returns back and the only things I'm getting back is a string of `"ReturnValue"`

```
Dim query As String = "insert into SHOP_HEADER (CATEGORY, DESCRIPTION, CONSUMABLE) values (?,?,?) RETURNING SI_KEY, PART_NO INTO :VAR_SI, :VAR_PART"

Using Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE)
    Using CMD As New OleDbCommand()
        With CMD
            .Connection = Conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CATEGORY", ListBox.SelectedValue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("DESCRIPTION", txtDescription.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CONSUMABLE", "0")
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("SI_KEY", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("PART_NO", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)

        End With
        Conn.Open()
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        VAR_SI = (CMD.Parameters("SI_KEY").Value.ToString)
        VAR_PART = (CMD.Parameters("PART_NO").Value.ToString)
    End Using
End Using
```

`VAR_SI` and `VAR_PART` then = `"ReturnValue`"

I've also tried changing `SI_KEY` and `PART_NO` to `VAR_SI` and `VAR_PART` in `CMD.Parameters` and `.Parameters.AddWithValue` as well with the same result.

**UPDATE WORKING**

Here's what I ended up doing and it works now.

```
Dim SIparam As New OleDbParameter()
SIparam.ParameterName = "VAR_SI"
SIparam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32
SIparam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output

Dim PARTparam As New OleDbParameter()
MTIparam.ParameterName = "VAR_PART"
MTIparam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32
MTIparam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output

Dim query As String = "insert into SHOP_HEADER (CATEGORY, DESCRIPTION, CONSUMABLE) values (?,?,?) RETURNING SI_KEY, PART_NO INTO :VAR_SI, :VAR_PART"

Using Conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStringToORACLE)
    Using CMD As New OleDbCommand()
        With CMD
            .Connection = Conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CATEGORY", ListBox.SelectedValue)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("DESCRIPTION", txtDescription.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CONSUMABLE", "0")
            .Parameters.Add(SIparam)
            .Parameters.Add(MTIparam)

        End With
        Conn.Open()
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        VAR_SI = (SIparam.Value)
        VAR_PART = (MTIparam.Value)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Have you tried adding them using .Add in place of .AddWithValue ?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer `Public Overloads Function Add(parameterName As String, value As Object) As OleDbParameter' is obsolete: 'Add(String parameterName, Object value) has been deprecated.  Use AddWithValue`

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ @lee

Comment: @AndrewMortimer `.Add` didn't produce different results.

Comment: Any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484135/how-to-get-two-return-value-from-oracle-stored-procedure ?

Comment: @Lee that's a different `.Add` overload. You want `.Add(parameterName, dataType)`. Not `.Add(parameterName, parameterValue)`.

Comment: I finally got it.  Updated above.  Thanks for the help Andrew and Bugs.